# Display conditional information based on a user's input to React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onchange, react-hook-form

I have a React form and I would like the user to be able to control the contents of a div based on the options they select in the form. I'd like this to happen onChange.

For example: if a user enters 'Pudding' into the select field, the div will display a list of puddings e.g. ice cream, cake, apple crumble. If a user enters 'Main', the div will display a list of mains e.g. steak, chicken, ham.

The concept seems pretty simple, but I'm new to React and an added layer of complexity is that I'm using [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) and need to use a [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller) because I will be using conditional logic to show and hide the form fields. Having said that, I'm not sure if this is relevant?!

**Structure of application**

```
  ----index.js---- 
   V             V
Form.js     MenuItems.js
   V
FormSelect.js
```

**FormSelect.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Select, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
function FormSelect({ values, name, question, register, control }) {
  const selectOptions = values;
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>What part of the menu do you want to see?</label>
      <Controller
        as={
          <Select>
               <MenuItem value="puddings">Puddings</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value="mains">Mains</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        }
        control={control}
        name={name}
        register={register}
        className="form-control"
        id={name}
        defaultValue=""
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default FormSelect;
```

**MenuItems.js**

```
import React from 'react;
const MenuItems = probs =>{
    return <div>This is where I want to show the list of foods!</div>;
};
export default MenuItems;
```

Is anyone able to advise what I'd need to do to my code to make this work?

Many thanks,

Katie